# Remove embed icon <> from flowplayer

Tags: css, video, flowplayer

Flowplayer has an icon on the top left of the video which is "<>". When you click on it comes up with message "Paste this HTML code on your site to embed."

I want to remove that icon from my videos.

So I changed the fp-embed to display:none as per below.

However its still not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">

      <title>Flowplayer · iframe src</title>

   <!-- optimize mobile versions -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <!-- The "minimalist" skin - choose from: "minimalist.css", "functional.css", "playful.css" -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.6/skin/playful.css">


<style type="text/css">
.fp-embed {
   display: none;
}
</style>

      <!-- Flowplayer depends on jquery -->
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Flowplayer library -->
   <script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.6/flowplayer.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="flowplayer color-light fixed-controls color-alt no-background"
     data-fullscreen="true">
   <video>
<source type="video/mp4"  src="http://example.com/example.mp4">
   </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

the above mentioned method will Never work. I wasted a lot of time in doing it just by css.

instead of this :

`<div class="flowplayer color-light fixed-controls color-alt no-background"
        data-fullscreen="true">`

use this :

`<div class="flowplayer color-light fixed-controls color-alt no-background"
     data-fullscreen="true" data-embed="false">`

Answer (score 2):

Your style gets overwritten by that of flowplayer itself. 
If you be more specific with your CSS style selector you will be able to hide it:

```
.flowplayer .fp-embed {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
flowplayer.conf = {
    embed : false
};
```

Rer.: https://flowplayer.org/docs/embedding.html#disabling-embedding